# Laravel eloquent One to Many relation

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I cannot figure out how to define one to many relation using `Eloquent`.

Here are tables

```
----------- Country -----------
id | title | code | currency_code

----------- Currency Code --------
id | name | symbol | code
```

One country may have many currencies.

Therefore I defined my models as follows

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function currencies()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Models\Currency', 'code', 'currency_code');
    }

}
```

And the Currency model is simple

```
class Currency extends Model
{


}
```

And I am selecting countries like that

```
   return Country::all('country_id AS value', 'title_ru AS title','currency_code')
   ->sortBy('value');
```

But it returns null when I try to access currencies

What is wrong with my definitions, I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: The docs provide good examples, please read them. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @LukeRamsden I have already read docs several times and it doesn't work

Comment: You might need to eager load the currencies in the query. Check the docs and see what applies

Comment: How/where do you access `currencies`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your model like the following code:

**Country model:**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'country';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function currency(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Currency', 'code', 'currency_code');
    }

}
```

**Currency model:**

```
class Currency extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'currency';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function country(){
        return $this->belongTo('App\Models\Country', 'code');
    }

}
```

And then if you wanna get a specific country data (with currency) you can use  this:

```
$data = County::where('id','=',$id)->with('currency')->first();
```

Or if you wanna get everything you can use:

```
$data = County::with('currency')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

**Country Model**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function currencies()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Currency', 'currency_code');
    }

}
```

**Currency Model**

```
class Currency extends Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am getting the following error `select * from `cdr_currencies` where `cdr_currencies`.`id` is null`

Comment: @bxfvgekd: Please give me full error so i will try to solve this